# Cython cannot convert python object to const float *

Tags: python, c++, arrays, cython

I am wrapping a plotting library written in C++, and am currently working on the final plot function. I am using [imgui-plot](https://github.com/soulthreads/imgui-plot), so credit goes to soulthreads for writing that. That being said, I have modified the code a bit by moving all the structs in the header file to parent level and then assigning them to the plotconfig struct.

Here are snippets of relevant code edited for readability:

**imgui-plot.h**

```
struct Values{
    const float xs* = nullptr
    const float ys* = nullptr
};

struct PlotConfig{
    Values values
};
```

**cimgui.pxd**

```
cdef extern from 'imgui-plot.h' namespace 'ImGui':
    cdef struct Values:
        const float xs*
        const float ys*

    cdef struct PlotConfig:
        Values values
```

**core.pyx**

```
import cimgui

def plot(x_data, y_data):
    cdef cimgui.PlotConfig conf
    conf.values.xs = x_data
    conf.values.ys = y_data

    cimgui.Plot(conf)
```

**Error I am getting**

```
> conf.values.xs = x_data

Cannot convert python object to 'const float *'
```

I tried putting the x_data in to a vector and making it non constant. I am realizing now that the error likely has something to do with the variable being a constant pointer or reference to memory location, and python's object abstraction of arrays.

Anyway, I would really appreciate some tips on this.

Comment: Does it work with `const double*`?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I imagine it would if you used ```vector[double]``` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering, these seems to have worked for me. I created a vector, pushed the values on to it, and assigned the pointer to the first value.

**core.pyx**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
import cimgui

def plot(x_data, y_data):
    cdef cimgui.PlotConfig conf
    cdef vector[float] x_s
    cdef vector[float] y_s

    for x in x_data:
      x_s.push_back(x)
    for y in y_data:
      y_s.push_back(y)

    conf.values.xs = &x_s[0]
    conf.values.ys = &y_s[0]

    cimgui.Plot(conf)
```